# Flask Templating Causing Duplicate HTML

Tags: python, twitter-bootstrap, flask, bokeh

For some reason when I use child templating with blocks in Flask, my HTML content is being rendered as duplicates. I am using Bootstrap and Bokeh to make graph visualizations. Each of the divs in my Dashboard.html child template are being rendered with duplicates. Does anyone know why this may be the case? Did I set up the templating incorrectly?

Below is my layout.html file:

**Layout.html**

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link type="text/css" href="index.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.12.16.min.css" type="text/css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.12.16.min.js"></script>
    <title>Embed Demo</title>

  </head>
  <body>


{% block body %}{% endblock %}


<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is my child template file:

**Dashboard.html**

```
 {% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block body %}
    {% for plot in plots %}
        {% for part in plot %}
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col" id="graphblock">
                  {{part | safe}}
            </div>
            <div class="col" id="graphblock">
                   {{part | safe}}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Here is my Flask server:

**Server.py**

```
import random
from flask import Flask, render_template
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.embed import components

app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='../static/dist', template_folder='../static/client')

@app.route('/dashboard/')
def show_dashboard():
    plots = []
    plots.append(make_plot())

    return render_template('dashboard.html', plots=plots)

def make_plot():
    plot = figure(plot_height=300, sizing_mode='scale_width')

    x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
    y = [2**v for v in x]

    plot.line(x, y, line_width=4)

    script, div = components(plot)
    return script, div

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Shouldn't make_plot() return one single value since you are appending the output of it to the plots array with plots.append()?

Answer (score 1):

Your template loop is not right. A `plot` in your `plots` list looks like: `(script, div)`. You loop over all the `plot` in `plots`, but then you also do this:

```
{% for part in plot %}
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col" id="graphblock">
      {{part | safe}}
    </div>
    <div class="col" id="graphblock">
      {{part | safe}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

The first iteration over a part includes the script twice, then the next iteration includes the div twice. This causes things to be duplicated.